# yii2 dataProvider- offset in dataprovider doesn't work

Tags: yii2, dataprovider

Offset is not working- is it correct? The pagination doesn't work.

```
$query = Event::find()
            ->offset(4)
            ->groupBy("sort_today");

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to set offset manually you need to switch off the pagination.

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => false
]);
```

Otherwise pagination [resets offset](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/data/ActiveDataProvider.php#L106) to whatever page is current.